# Why might I see this OpenGL spherical mapping artifact in GLSL?

Tags: opengl, geometry, textures, glsl

[image: Globe Artifact]

I'm trying to map a globe texture onto a sphere. I'm using a plate carrée (Equirectangular) map projection, and there's this meridian which has this "blurring". What's strange is that the blurring isn't around a singularity in my texture (which occurs right down the pacific ocean in this example). Instead, the defect occurs around the (s,t) = (0.5, ?) point.

Have I done something really stupid?

EDIT: And to prove the model's not strange, here's the same thing on a teapot:

[image: Teapot Artifact]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You cannot generate texture coordinates like that.

The problem is that really quite simple. At 359 degrees, the S texture coordinate will be something like 0.95 or so. Close to 1.0, but not equal to 1.0. At 0 degrees, which *physically* is a position directly adjacent to the last position, the texture coordinate will be 0.0. So you will interpolate between 0.95 and 0.0. It doesn't go around the other way.

This is one of the many reasons why cubemaps exist. You can't get around this problem without either cubemaps or changing the topology of your mesh.

Comment: Ahh.. makes sense (+1). What do you mean "changing the topology of the mesh"?

Comment: Otherwise you could use pre-generated UVs

Comment: @Krom: That just shifts the problem somewhere else. I'd still have to generate the coordinates somehow.

Comment: @BillyONeal: Your problem is the mesh topology. You need to have some positions which are repeated, so that one position is paired with the texture coordinate 0 and the other position (which is the same value) is paired with the texture coordinate 1. So you have the same position with two different texture coordinates. This is common in graphics when dealing with wrapping textures.

Comment: @NicolBolas: It's a singularity. I don't think there's any way to completely eliminate such things. By moving the calculation into the fragment shader though I at least was able to get something halfway decent. There's still a visible line; but it's a line. Not a whole blurry region.

Comment: @BillyONeal: Yes there is. You do exactly what I said: duplicate the vertices so that you have the same position with two texture coordinates. This is a *solved problem*; it's been known about since forever. It is simply a matter of not using texture coordinate generation; you create the texture coordinates offline, just as you would for any normal mesh.

Comment: @BillyONeal: Exactly. That shifts the problem to a place where it can be solved easily.

Comment: @Nicol: I have no means of accomplishing that at present time. I'm using meshes provided by someone else, and they don't include texture mapping information. I wouldn't have the first idea how to generate such a mesh myself.

Comment: @Krom: I don't see why the problem is any easier to solve by passing in texture coordinates in C++ land than it is by generating the coordinates in GLSL land. You'll still have the same problem.

Comment: I was referring to passing the UV generation to "3dMax", there are plenty of UV-unwrap tools if you need anything more complex than a sphere. If you need only simple forms (spheres, cones, etc) spherically mapped, then do as Nicol says - change your topology to have a discontinuous mesh. It all depends on your goal in the end.

Comment: @Billy ONeal.  Learn to use modo or Blender.  If the right way to solve the problem was via programming, 3D content creation apps would not exist.

Comment: @Jessy: I am a programmer. I was led to understand that this was a bug in my code. I am not a graphic designer or artist, and have no desire to learn an entire new environment dedicated to those kinds of work.

Comment: @Billy: "have no desire to learn an entire new environment dedicated to those kinds of work." Then why are you doing graphics? If you want to have any success as a graphics programmer, you're going to need at least basic proficiency in various graphics packages. You can't just take stuff off the net, slap it into your code, and expect it all to work perfectly.

Comment: @NicolBolas: Because I wanted to learn GLSL. The models were provided as part of a class.